# Set specific DNS server using dns.resolver (pythondns)

Tags: python, dns

I am using `dns.resolver` from [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/).

Is it possible to set the IP address of the server to use for queries ?

Comment: Can you add a link to the library which provides `dns.resolver`? Also, wouldn't that be in the `dns.resolver` docs?

Comment: @WoLpH In ubunty there is a package named `python-dnspython`

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Although this is somewhat of an old thread, I will jump in. I've bumped against the same challenge and I thought I would share the solution. So, basically the config file would populate the 'nameservers' instance variable of the dns.resolver.Resolver you are using. Hence, if you want to coerce your Resolver to use a particular nameserver, you can do it direcly like this:

```
import dns.resolver

my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()

# 8.8.8.8 is Google's public DNS server
my_resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']

answer = my_resolver.query('google.com')
```

Hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: You could pass `configure=False` to avoid reading `/etc/resolv.conf` or Windows registry.

Comment: You can checkout their git repository and manually switch the branch to `python3`.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this answer (as I did), `dnspython` now supports Python 3.x (and 2.x if you're still using it).

Comment: does anyone know how to verify which server answered? I couldn't find it in any of the method and also not in answer.response.to_text()

Comment: Updated answer for 2021: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65788144/1438393

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is.

If you use the convenience function `dns.resolver.query()` like this

```
import dns.resolver
r = dns.resolver.query('example.org', 'a')
```

you can re-initialize the default resolver such such a specific nameserver (or a list) is used, e.g.:

```
import dns.resolver
dns.resolver.default_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
dns.resolver.default_resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8', '2001:4860:4860::8888',
                                             '8.8.4.4', '2001:4860:4860::8844' ]
r = dns.resolver.query('example.org', 'a')
```

Or you can use a separate resolver object just for some queries:

```
import dns.resolver
res = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
res.nameservers = [ '8.8.8.8', '2001:4860:4860::8888',
                    '8.8.4.4', '2001:4860:4860::8844' ]
r = res.query('example.org', 'a')
```

Answer (score 12):

Since there's no example of how to do this with dnspython in 2021, I thought I'd post one:

```
import dns.resolver

resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8'] # using google DNS
result = resolver.resolve('google.com', 'NS')
nameservers = [ns.to_text() for ns in result]
```

Output:

```
['ns1.google.com.', 'ns3.google.com.', 'ns2.google.com.', 'ns4.google.com.']
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Resolver' object has no attribute 'resolve'` using last version of `dnspython`.

Comment: @e-info128: Make sure you're on dnspython 2.0.0 or above. See [the documentation](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew.html#id3).

Comment: Yes, `dnspython==2.1.0` from `pip3`. I solve this using same example but replacing `.resolve()` by `.query()`.

Comment: that's kinda curious, considering when I try to use `.query()` it works but gives a warning about the query function being deprecated, and orienting to use the `.resolve()` function instead, exactly like this answer points to.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify in your question, but assuming you're using [the resolver from dnspython.org](http://www.dnspython.org/), the documentation indicates you want to set the [`nameservers`](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.8.0/html/dns.resolver.Resolver-class.html#nameservers) attribute on the Resolver object.

Though it may be easier to provide an /etc/resolv.conf-style file to pass to the [constructor's `filename` argument](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.8.0/html/dns.resolver.Resolver-class.html#__init__).

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` is not used on Windows.