# dnsPython use IP on interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns

I use dsnPython in a project.
I use many resolvers same as explained at [Set specific DNS server using dns.resolver (pythondns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898363/python-dns-resolver-set-specific-dns-server).
In order to send several requests I need to dispatch my request on many IPs.
I have some IPs on my interface eth0.

Do you know a way to send a request through an specific IP ?

Comment: Why, if I may ask, do you need to dispatch your request on many IPs? Why can't you send all of your requests from the same IP? Or, why can't you let the OS choose the source IP automatically?

Comment: Because I will send about one million requests in the shortest time. So if I don't want that DNS blacklist me I must parrallelize my requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible by using resolvers and source attribute :

```
import dns.resolver

my_resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']
answer = my_resolver.query(
    qname = fqdn_port,
    source = '1.2.3.4',
)
```

**8.8.8.8** is the resolver IP

**1.2.3.4** is an IP of server