# Socket resolve DNS with specific DNS server

Tags: python, sockets, dns

I want to resolve DNS with specific DNS server, for example Google's 8.8.8.8. My actual Python code is:

```
import socket

def getIP(d):
    try:
        data = socket.gethostbyname(d)
        ip = repr(data)
        return True
    except Exception:
        # fail gracefully!
        return False
```

Is it possible using Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python, dns.resolver, set specific dns server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898363/python-dns-resolver-set-specific-dns-server)

Comment: this dns.resolver not work in mac os :(

Comment: @seoexpert I've just tested dns.resolver on Mac OS X (El Capitan) and it works perfectly fine! I've updated my answer below to include Max OS X install instructions.

Comment: Not really, @MarcB, as OP here wasn't even aware if `pythondns` library existence. And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898363/python-dns-resolver-set-specific-dns-server assumes that you are using it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use dnspython: http://www.dnspython.org/
On ubuntu/debian you can get it using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dnspython
```

Otherwise get it via:

```
sudo pip install dnspython
```

Or download the source install it via:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Your code would be something like this:

```
from dns import resolver

res = resolver.Resolver()
res.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']

answers = res.query('stackexchange.com')

for rdata in answers:
    print (rdata.address)
```

Edit:
Since the OP seems to have issues using it on Mac OS X here is what I did to get it installed (for local user only):

```
git clone git://github.com/rthalley/dnspython.git
cd dnspython
python setup.py install --user
```

Comment: I managed to install `dnspython` on El Capitan normally using pip but with `pip>=8.1.0` (see https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2350#issuecomment-192895732).

Comment: `sudo` should not be needed for python package installation

Answer (score 10):

`dnspython` is a mature library, but maybe overkill for someone who get here. So, I provide a simple single-file [implementation](https://github.com/1ocalhost/py_cheat/blob/master/dns_lookup.py).

```
import socket
import ipaddress


def parse_dns_string(reader, data):
    res = ''
    to_resue = None
    bytes_left = 0

    for ch in data:
        if not ch:
            break

        if to_resue is not None:
            resue_pos = chr(to_resue) + chr(ch)
            res += reader.reuse(resue_pos)
            break

        if bytes_left:
            res += chr(ch)
            bytes_left -= 1
            continue

        if (ch >> 6) == 0b11 and reader is not None:
            to_resue = ch - 0b11000000
        else:
            bytes_left = ch

        if res:
            res += '.'

    return res


class StreamReader:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.pos = 0

    def read(self, len_):
        pos = self.pos
        if pos >= len(self.data):
            raise

        res = self.data[pos: pos+len_]
        self.pos += len_
        return res

    def reuse(self, pos):
        pos = int.from_bytes(pos.encode(), 'big')
        return parse_dns_string(None, self.data[pos:])


def make_dns_query_domain(domain):
    def f(s):
        return chr(len(s)) + s

    parts = domain.split('.')
    parts = list(map(f, parts))
    return ''.join(parts).encode()


def make_dns_request_data(dns_query):
    req = b'\xaa\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    req += dns_query
    req += b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'
    return req


def add_record_to_result(result, type_, data, reader):
    if type_ == 'A':
        item = str(ipaddress.IPv4Address(data))
    elif type_ == 'CNAME':
        item = parse_dns_string(reader, data)
    else:
        return

    result.setdefault(type_, []).append(item)


def parse_dns_response(res, dq_len, req):
    reader = StreamReader(res)

    def get_query(s):
        return s[12:12+dq_len]

    data = reader.read(len(req))
    assert(get_query(data) == get_query(req))

    def to_int(bytes_):
        return int.from_bytes(bytes_, 'big')

    result = {}
    res_num = to_int(data[6:8])
    for i in range(res_num):
        reader.read(2)
        type_num = to_int(reader.read(2))

        type_ = None
        if type_num == 1:
            type_ = 'A'
        elif type_num == 5:
            type_ = 'CNAME'

        reader.read(6)
        data = reader.read(2)
        data = reader.read(to_int(data))
        add_record_to_result(result, type_, data, reader)

    return result


def dns_lookup(domain, address):
    dns_query = make_dns_query_domain(domain)
    dq_len = len(dns_query)

    req = make_dns_request_data(dns_query)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.settimeout(2)

    try:
        sock.sendto(req, (address, 53))
        res, _ = sock.recvfrom(1024 * 4)
        result = parse_dns_response(res, dq_len, req)
    except Exception:
        return
    finally:
        sock.close()

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dns_lookup('www.stackoverflow.com', "8.8.8.8"))
```

output:

```
{'CNAME': ['stackoverflow.com'], 'A': ['151.101.1.69', '151.101.65.69', '151.101.129.69', '151.101.193.69']}
```

Comment: Thank you for this implementation.  It came in handy when one of our users didn't have dig or nslookup available but did have a python interpreter.

Comment: That is cool. Thank you for sharing it! I'll give it a try at a Busybox created embedded Linux which comes without DNS resolving...