# Windows DNS problem with Python socket.getaddrinfo()

Tags: python-3.x, windows, dns

I have DNS problems with my Python scripts, but not with network tools or browser on my Windows 10 desktop.

Running my scripts every network request takes at least 5-10 seconds. Profiling with py-spy with the --idle flag identified socket.getaddrinfo() as the function spent most time in. I tested in the Python REPL with following command:

```
socket.getaddrinfo("example.org", 80, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
```

It took around 5-10 seconds to return. Setting fixed DNS server in my active network interface did change anything.

Rebooting fixes the problem and brings down the respons time below second times. But after keeping the computer up for some days, the problem returns.

It looks like socket.getaddrinfo hits some timeout and then resolves with the correct DNS.

`nslookup` works just fine. Response time in ms. Also internet surfing in browsers works just fine.

Any ideas where I could start to dig?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?
Resolving a Domain Name to an IP address?

1. simply try:
   socket.gethostbyname("example.com")
2. check which dns servers are configured (in cmd- ipconfig /all,  DNS Servers category).
3. Try using a propriety python DNS client, see if the problem persists.
   e.g. dnspython

(See this answer -
[Socket resolve DNS with specific DNS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793061/socket-resolve-dns-with-specific-dns-server))

Comment: Sory for the late reply. Thanks for your suggestions. 

It's part of a client library for Shopify's REST API I use. There is no way I could change the code there. I use the library on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. Only on Windows the problem arises after days of uptime. Maybe a ocassional reboot is is the way to go and it's not worth to trace down further.