# query with different name server

Tags: python, dns, dnspython

I am going to change the default name server of a domain and then get its A records! I tried to use the following code but the problem is that when I use the IP address as name server every thing works but when I used name server name such as "ns1.google.com" I could not run the code and got exception. Any thought?(I used the code from here: [Set specific DNS server using dns.resolver (pythondns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898363/set-specific-dns-server-using-dns-resolver-pythondns))

```
def NsLookupSpecificNS(domain):
    my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()

    # 8.8.8.8 is Google's public DNS server
    my_resolver.nameservers = ['216.239.38.10']

    answer = my_resolver.query('google.com', 'A')
    try:
        for rdata in answer:
            print rdata
    except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
            pass
```

I have tired the following:

```
def NsLookupSpecificNS(domain):
    my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()

    # 8.8.8.8 is Google's public DNS server
    my_resolver.nameservers = ['ns1.google.com']

    answer = my_resolver.query('google.com', 'A')
    try:
        for rdata in answer:
            print rdata
    except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
            pass
```

And here is what I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\DNS\Lookup.py", line 49, in <module>
    NsLookupSpecificNS('google.com')
  File "C:\Users\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\DNS\Lookup.py", line 33, in NsLookupSpecificNS
    answer = my_resolver.query('google.com', 'A')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 962, in query
    source_port=source_port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dns\query.py", line 242, in udp
    if _addresses_equal(af, from_address, destination) or \
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dns\query.py", line 169, in _addresses_equal
    n2 = dns.inet.inet_pton(af, a2[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dns\inet.py", line 51, in inet_pton
    return dns.ipv4.inet_aton(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dns\ipv4.py", line 48, in inet_aton
    raise dns.exception.SyntaxError
dns.exception.SyntaxError: Text input is malformed.
```

Comment: what exception ? Always put in question full error message. There are many usefull information.

Comment: where is dns.resolver coming from?

Comment: @furas I updated the question!

Comment: @Stephen I am not sure! I am new in this area and got the code from examples on internet

Comment: I can not test if i do not have the dns code, where is it from?  Put that info into the question so that anyone interested can help.

Comment: but i do not think it would be related to resolver! because in the first part when I use ip then I get the result but only when I change ip to name then I got the error

Comment: I understand.  But try to understand that you are trying to get other people to help with your problem. On SO, there are many, many questions.  The ones that get a quick answers are the ones that are the easiest to answer.  If the person who is trying to answer a question must go and find many different things to answer the question, they may just move on and not bother. So the more that you can do to make it easy to answer your question, the more likely that someone will answer it. :-)

Comment: Great point. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dnspython, the nameservers instance variable takes a list of ip addresses and not domain names and that's why you're getting that error. You'll need to separately query for the address of ns1.google.com and use that address (or addresses) for the subsequent query. Of course, that begs the question of where you make that first query. For that, you can try using the system resolver.