# specify custom dns server on gae

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I have a gae application that needs to consume a third party api. That api is accessible via a url that can only be resolved through use of a dns server supplied by that third party.

Is there any way for me to point my gae application at that specific DNS server instead of the default ones?

I assume the answer is no, but it's a difficult thing to google for because I keep getting search results about how to set up a custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

The [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) package supports queries while specifying the nameservers to use, see 
[Set specific DNS server using dns.resolver (pythondns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898363/set-specific-dns-server-using-dns-resolver-pythondns).

It does use sockets, though, which are only available to paid apps. There were some problems reported with it a while back, but they appear to be resolved, I guess it's worth a try (personally I didn't use it).

Related: [[google-app-engine] dnspython](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgoogle-app-engine%5d%20dnspython)